# Use mono api to generate a .net assembly ( exe/dll )

Tags: .net, mono, cil

I'm seeking some api to allow me to generate IL code for a program written in C (unmanaged program), after some research I found that the GCC than targets to msil code uses the mono API to fetch the metadata information, classes and methods of .NET assemblies, So, I wonder, how can I use the Mono API to generate MSIL code ?

---

Exist some more better API to do this ?

I know I can use the API that Microsoft provides, but not be able to use this api in windows!

---

http://www.giorgosdimtsas.net/embedding-mono-in-your-c-application/

http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=root:/embed

Comment: I use `System.Reflection.Emit` (also implemented in Mono), works pretty well.